# Terminal screen coordinates in python

Tags: python, screen, url-rewriting

I'm newbie in using curses lib. I want to make a python program (running in a DOS terminal) that can return the cursor to the start of the current line allowing subsequent output to overwrite what was previously written there. I tried to call a shellscript from python to do it, but I beleive it may exist a better way for doing it.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What have you tried?)

Comment: See if your curses library has a `move(y, x)` function.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: yes, DOS like in Windows.

Comment: @martineau: No it does, but i want to get the position cursor so I can  do later a move(y,x).

Comment: Oh, OK. Check for a curses library function `getyx()`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is rewrite the current line, just print a return char "\r". For example, this prints "ABCdef":

```
# print 'abcdef' then backup to start of line, then print 'ABC'
# (then print the normal cr/lf that 'print' always does)
print "abcdef\rABC"
```

(Also helpful to know that you can suppress the cr/lf by ending your print with a trailing comma...)
.

Comment: Thks for responding. I actually want to rewrite a previous line no the current one. Is it possible?

Comment: In DOS (and now on Windows), `\r` returns to the beginning of the line and `\n` moves the cursor down one line.  But this depends on the terminal type.  Strictly speaking, in terms of the Unicode standard, `\r` and `\n` are considered device controls, not characters, and their meaning is not specified by Unicode.  So be careful.